# How WPF Connect With Remote DB on server or some Other PC Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I need to connect my **WPF desktop app** with **remote DB on other system or Server(online)** with **Entity Framework**. What i have to do. I need some initial connection steps 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the connection setting in your connection string in the config file of your project as described in:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e80a1707-4977-4bc2-bae4-f51b9fa3fedb/connect-entity-framework-to-remote-server-database-?forum=adodotnetentityframework